# Why is there a difference between a = a + b and a += b

Tags: python, list, operators

I just encountered this bug:

```
def fn_that_uses_a_list(list):
  if (list[-1] < 0): list += [0]
  for item in list:
    print(item)

l = [-4, -2]
fn_that_uses_a_list(l)
# Now suddenly l has three items.
```

However, if I change `list += [0]` to `list = list + [0]`, then things work. I find this confusing, but it could be because I'm new to Python.

Why is there a difference in this case? I'm looking for a more existential answer, rather than "`list` is a reference so `+=` modifies the original"

Am I doing something "un-pythonic" that's causing me to run into the bug?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Don't you want list to have three items after the function?

Comment: What's wrong here !!

Comment: @syntonym No. I temporarily need a list with three items during the function. I still need the original list to stay the same after calling the function...

Comment: Well, using `list` as a variable name is a bit unpythonic to start with.  But if it's your *intent* to create a new list, then I'd use a new variable name for that new list in your code: `my_new_list = list + [0] if list[-1] < 0 else list`.  That'll prevent you from running into the `+=` trap.  OTOH, if it's your intent to modify the incoming list, then it looks like you're getting exactly the behaviour that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are after, if I use both `list += [0]` and `list = list + [0]` I get the same result.

That said, `+=` mutates the list, while `+` creates a new list. Try:

```
def fn_that_uses_a_list(list):
  if (list[-1] < 0):
    print id(list)
    list += [0]
    # list = list + [0]
    print id(list)
  for item in list:
    print(item)

l = [-4, -2]
fn_that_uses_a_list(l)
```

Comment: I think the intend was not that the `print`s print something differently, but the mutation of the list takes place.